# How to find marginal pdf from a piecewise joint distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> Given$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)= \begin{cases} \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}, &0\le y\le x\le 1 \\\displaystyle\frac{3}{2}, & 1 \le x \le 2-y \le 2 \end{cases}$$
> Find conditional pdfs $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ and $f_{Y|X}(y|x).$

To solve this I'm trying to find the marginal pdfs. I can maybe (I'm not sure if this correct) see $f_Y(y)$ being found as $\displaystyle\int_xf_{X,Y}(x,y)dx= \displaystyle\int\limits^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{2}dx+\int\limits^{2}_{1}\frac{3}{2}dx.$ But I don't understand how to find $f_{X}(x)$ since y takes values between $0$ and $1$ for both the given probabilities.

Could someone please guide me how to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Take another look at the support of the joint distribution. For finding $f_Y$, you can have either $y\le x\le1$ or $1\le x\le2-y$. Hence$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx=\int_y^1\frac12\,dx+\int_1^{2-y}\frac32\,dx$$

For finding $f_X$, notice that $y$ has a different upper bound depending on the value of $x$:

$$x<1 \implies 0 \le y \le x \\
x>1 \implies x\le 2-y \le 2 \implies 0\le y\le 2-x$$
Then the marginal wrt $x$ has two corresponding cases,
$$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy = \begin{cases}\displaystyle\int_0^x \frac12\,dy & x<1 \\[2ex] \displaystyle\int_0^{2-x} \frac32\,dy & x>1 \end{cases}$$

---

> ... reason for taking the limits of the integral for $f_Y(y)$ as functions of $y$ ...?

It always helps to sketch out the situation.

[image]

In the blue triangle, $x$ is bounded to the left by the line $x=y$, and to the right by the line $x=1$. If instead you allow $x$ to go as low as $0$, you are effectively integrating over the rectangle $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. But the joint density is $0$ there when $(x,y)$ falls above $y=x$, so you end up getting more than you should be. The same goes for the orange triangle.

You can verify that the result of your integral will not make for a valid density function:

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}\displaystyle \int\limits^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{2}dx+\int\limits^{2}_{1}\frac{3}{2}dx = 2 & 0\le x\le2\\[1ex]
0 & \rm else\end{cases} \\
\implies \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \, dx = \int_0^2 2\,dx = 4 \neq 1$$

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the dumb question but is there a reason for taking the limits of the integral for $f_{Y}(y)$ as functions of $y$ instead of just $0$ and $2$?

Comment: @thecountofmontecristo Hopefully the edit helps explain why

Comment: More simply: $f_Y(y)$ *is* a function of $y$, so too must the integral of the joint pdf remain one (and thus the region of integration with respect to $x$ must be bounded by that fixed value of $y$ in the support).